# display carriage return from mysql

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I have the following field :

```
mysql> select content from campaign where cid = 489;
+------------------------------+
| content                      | 
+------------------------------+
| hi
  how are you?
  wie gehts? |
+------------------------------+
```

and want to display on html, but when i used

```
<sql:transaction dataSource="${dataBase}">
    <sql:query var="tAdmin">
        SELECT content FROM campaign
    </sql:query>
</sql:transaction>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${tAdmin.rows}" varStatus="totalRow" step="1">
    <c:set var="myContent" value="${row.content}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

and then:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    element.innerHTML='${myContent}';
</script>
```

it showed blank on browser. Any idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this [EL wiki stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and did something like the following:

```
1. Create new line to <br/> conversion file so-called Functions.java under WEB-INF/org/global:

   package org.global;

   public final class Functions {
   private Functions() {}

    public static String nl2br(String string) {
           return (string != null) ? string.replace("\r\n", "<br/>") : null;
       }
   }

2. Create new TLD file so-called Functions.tld under WEB-INF/tld or wherever TLD files reside:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <taglib
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
    <short-name>New_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://global.org/functions</uri>

    <function>
      <name>nl2br</name>
      <function-class>org.global.Functions</function-class>
      <function-signature>java.lang.String nl2br(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
     </function>

   </taglib>

 3. Add this line on the respective .jsp file :

    <%@taglib uri="http://global.org/functions" prefix="f" %>

    and finally use the function prefix :

    ${f:nl2br(row.content)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:
select replace(temp, '
', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) INTO outString from dual;

This is Oracle SQL btw.

So you would write your current SQL (SELECT content FROM campaign) as a sub-query:

select replace(SELECT content FROM campaign, '<br />', CHR(13)||CHR(10))  from dual;

Comment: I tried with SELECT REPLACE(content,'\r\n','<br\\>') FROM campaign and worked only on command line but still not showed up on browser. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, not sure but maybe you have to escape the C:set command escapeXml.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html

Comment: Where is the JavaScript being called?? Is there more to this page, because I think my initial thought was completely wrong.<br/>When you say the page is blank, do you mean like your JavScript function (element.innerHTML='${myContent}';) is working at all?

Comment: Still not working with escapeXml. JavaScript element.innerHTML='${myContent}' is working fine except for those carriage return stuffs.